# May I know what language is this? is this javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

these code makes me confuse, I would like to add an image for this variable but idk what is the code of adding an image is it image: ? or picture: ?

```
    var goldStar = {
      path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
      fillColor: 'yellow',
      fillOpacity: 0.8,
      scale: 1,
      strokeColor: 'gold',
      strokeWeight: 14
    };
```

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript, but no jQuery is used in the code you posted. That's a JavaScript variable declaration and initialization.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking here and how it relates to the tags you used

Comment: but how could I know what is the code of adding an image to this variable .... the code is too messy and I can't find it on internet

Comment: because get these code from google map api

Comment: I suggest you read Google map api documentation and then ask specific question.

Comment: your question is not clear .. What you are trying to do  .. add  an image on google maps ,?  .  add a marker  ?  .. add an icon  .. your r code is not enough for understand your need ... anyway the code provided is javascript and is for set an icon on goglle maps based on SVG

Comment: I want to add a custom marker icon to my map but the I the image that I wanted to use to the marker icon is too big so I was planning to adjust the size of the image by css. so this is why I wanted to know the mean of these code..

Comment: I have read all the google map api documentation which related about how to modify the marker icon and these code is what I find which can help me to modify my image, but I don't know how to put an image to this variable,..

Comment: @李晓东   i have poste an aswer  hope is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for add  an image as marker icon  .. you can simply assign the path  to the icon attribute

assuming your icon (image) is stored in

```
var myIcon = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parking_lot_maps.png';

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: myIcon,
        map: map
      });
```